# MATLAB Word counter

Tags: string, matlab

I need to write code that counts the number of occurrences of each word in a string. If the string has multiple rows, I treat each row as a separate string. Here is what I have so far. I know that after I find 2 words that match, I update the number of occurrences and change the second word to the empty string, so it doesn't get matched again. My code does't do each word, it does the whole string. Can anyone assist me? I also know I need to utilize regexp(), but I'm not sure how.

```
[row col] = size(str);
if(row > 1)
    fprintf('You inputted %.0f strings\n',row);
    cArr = cellstr(str);
    for index=1:row-1
        for index2=2:row-1
            numOcc = 1;
            x = cArr(index); 
            y = cArr(index2);
            isSame = strcmp(x,y);
            if isSame == 1
                numOcc = numOcc + 1;
                y = '';
            end;
        end;
    end;
    z = char(x); 
    fprintf('%s: %.0f\n',x,numOcc);
end;

Example output:
str =
This string should be the first row.
This string should be the second row, or should it?
>> wordhist(str)
You inputted 2 strings.
String 1
This: 1
string: 1
should: 1
be: 1
the: 1
first: 1
row: 1
String 2
This: 1
string: 1
should: 2
be: 1
the: 1
second: 1
row: 1
or: 1
it: 1
```

Comment: I think you need a clearer explanation of what you're trying to do (maybe an example). Also, look into the [strsplit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) and [strfind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) functions.

Comment: You can edit your question with the example so that the formatting is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that just deals with one string at a time, and doesn't worry about punctuation (it just splits on spaces). You'll have to work on those two things to get them to your liking. This example is largely taken from a [Matlab Central question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/39759-word-frequency).

```
% an example string
str = 'This string is an example string to test if there is a working string counter.'
% the words in the string (use regexp for more advanced e.g., punctuation)
words = strsplit(str, ' ');
% unique words in the cell array
[uwords, idw, idu] = unique(words);
% counts for each word corresponding to idw
n = accumarray(idu,1);
% display the counts
for i = 1:numel(n)
  fprintf('%s: %i\n', words{idw(i)}, n(i));
end
```

The output is:

```
str =
  This string is an example string to test if there is a working string counter.

This: 1
a: 1
an: 1
counter.: 1
example: 1
if: 1
is: 2
string: 3
test: 1
there: 1
to: 1
working: 1
```